# TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float in plt.imshow() python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, concatenation, opencv

I want to read each image founded in `paths` and concatenate them using `vconcat`. I got this error
`Traceback : in plt.imshow(im_v,cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest') TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float`  while running the below code. How to solve it ??

Any help would be appreciated.

```
if nSpectogram <3765:
            for k in range (0,22):
                paths=FirstPartPathOutput+SecondPartPathOutput+'/spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k)
                for f1 in paths:
                    img = cv2.imread(f1)
                    im_v=cv2.vconcat(img)
                plt.imshow(im_v,cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')

            plt.axis('off') 
            plt.savefig(FirstPartPathOutput+SecondPartPathOutput+'/spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k+1)+'.png')
```

Comment: convert im_v to float type first by yourself first? You should check what values im_v have...

Comment: @ted930511 im_v have None value. I expected that images have concatenated.I don't know why I got None value

Comment: Normally I dont use cv, I use numpy `vstack`, `hstack` or `dstack`, why not print the shape of im_v or img in the loop? You have alot to try. There must be something wrong with img, then caused issue for im_v